# How to replace accountExpires in LDAP / AD using ldapadd?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

My ldif-file is:

```
dn: CN=Test Person,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=oof,DC=rab,DC=de
changetype: modify
replace: accountExpires
accountExpires: 9223372036854775808
```

The output:

```
root@comp:~# ldapadd -h host -f test.ldif
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: [...]
SASL SSF: 56
SASL installing layers
modifying entry "CN=Test Person,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=oof,DC=rab,DC=de"
ldapadd: Invalid syntax (21)
additional info: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090B7C, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v1db0
```

What am I doing wrong? Where is the wrong syntax?

All other things like DN, connection, host et cetera are checked and okay.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I passed the maximum (set as default by the AD when creating a user), because this did work:

```
dn: CN=Test Person,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=oof,DC=rab,DC=de
changetype: modify
replace: accountExpires
accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
```

(... and by the way: It's the Long.MAX_VALUE). Bad idea to increment this on my test ...